# How do I make the objects appear again after they disappeared

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I make the objects appear again after they get out of display like video below? ("Avoid objects" in video)

[Video (Does not belong to me)](https://youtu.be/lmXqwKIIXQI)

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look here for how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood your problem.

What you are looking to do is check whether the player has crossed any of the corners of the screen and then simply move him back to the start :

Let's say that x and y are your character coordinates.
I'll make the assumption that the top left corner of your terrain is at position (0,0)
What you have to do is check whether x or y are above/below the limits:

```
if(x > terrainXEndpoint){
   x = 0;
}
if(x < 0){
   x=terrainXEndpoint;
}

if(y > terrainYEndpoint){
   y = 0;
} 
if(y<0){
   y=terrainYEndpoint;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I already got -3 points for the reason that I don't know. 

I thought the objects that moving around the layout are numbered, so you mean they aren't? It always create new one after one disappeared?

Comment: I don't know the reason of all the downvotes, I don't think your question is bad

Comment: The 4 close votes are because your question is too broad. I agree, though, it's best if people give feedback when down-voting. Probably asking a more specific question, with some code sample will help.